# How can I correctly calculate bias for a group of forecasts combined using the mean?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a monthly time serie and I want to generate 4 forecasts (using ets(),auto.arima(), nnetar() and combining the results of the 3 using the mean). I did the following:

```
library(forecast)
train<-ts(USAccDeaths,end=c(1977,12),frequency=12)
test<-ts(USAccDeaths,start=c(1978,1),end=c(1978,12),frequency=12)


forecast1 <- forecast(ets(train),h=12)$mean
forecast2 <- forecast(auto.arima(train),h=12)$mean
forecast3 <- forecast(nnetar(train),h=12)$mean
forecast4 <- (forecast1+forecast2+forecast3)/3
```

After it I calculated MSE for all of them:

```
MSE1<-mean((forecast1-test)^2)
MSE2<-mean((forecast2-test)^2)
MSE3<-mean((forecast3-test)^2)
MSEComb<-mean((forecastComb-test)^2)
```

My questions is: how can i calculate the bias for forecast1, forecast2, forecast3 and forecastComb (combination of forecasts)?

Thanks!